# Software redistribution - package dependencies vs stand-alone

Tags: package-management, application-development, qt, debian

I have a small application and want to redistribute it to other Ubuntu users. The QT library is used

I will distrbute it as easy-to-install debian package

My question is, should I put QT packages as required dependency (and force users to download and install it) or is a stand-alone build a better choice?

What would a normal Ubuntu user prefer, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the target releases have the corresponding Qt version's packages, set them as a required dependency.

I don't want to depend on $RANDOM_DEV to rebuild packages in case the libraries or other third-party components get critical/security bug patches. I'd rather depend on my OS' package maintainers for that. I would also rather not have multiple copies of the library lying around for different apps.

OTOH, snaps include the libraries, and the same problems apply: [Do I have to create a new snap package everytime a dependency gets a security update?](https://askubuntu.com/q/787400/158442) - but snaps at least have sandboxing.