# "core - The core runtime enviornment for snapd." What is it and how did it get on my computer?

Tags: installed-programs

Just installed Ubuntu on a new laptop I bought (came with Win 10).  Three days later, in my installed programs in the Ubuntu Software, I see:

core - The core runtime enviornment for snapd

I didn't install this (that I can remember).

What is it?
What does it do?
Do I need it?

Comment: That question is talking about shared dependencies and doesn't get to the point of what is it and what is it doing.  I also wonder how does it get added without my permission - is it the result of an extension, say from Chrome?

Comment: Read this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/787149/how-do-snap-packages-handle-shared-dependencies/873293#873293 *all installed snap packages except for the core snap depend on two packages, one of which is the core snap. 1. snapd - which is installed by default in 16.04 and onwards and can also be installed in 14.04. 2. core - (the core snap) which is automatically downloaded and installed when the first installed snap package is installed*

Answer (score 0):

**core** is the name of a Snap package. Snaps are containerised software packages that are simple to create and install. They auto-update and are safe to run. And because they bundle their dependencies with them, they are not distribution dependent.

The Snap package **core** contains the low level dependencies (when you install an app, dependencies are the packages that aren’t part that app but are needed for the app to run properly) needed by all Snap apps. So yes, you definitely need it if you want your system to be able to run [snap apps](https://snapcraft.io/).