# Is snaps sharing libraries?

Tags: snap, libraries, sharing

I have one big question in regards of snaps. Is it sharing libraries?
The reason why I ask is because that was one of the things that I was so impressed by when starting with ubuntu, that it was sharing libraries, and therefore saves space on the disk. Does snaps still do this? or am I totally wrong about apt?

Comment: Related: [How do snap packages handle shared dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787149/how-do-snap-packages-handle-shared-dependencies)

Comment: You're right about apt. If you want shared libraries and saved space, then use apt for it. If you want to use a specific version of an older or newer stack, use a snap for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee with either snaps nor apt/dpkg, that the app you are using, is relying on system-wide shared libraries, for every dependency they have.

Depending on how a snap is built, it may be using some libraries shared with other snaps (the core snap includes a libc and libstdc++ for example), but neither direction is as simple as it might seem, when it comes down to stability, security, and ensuring users get the latest features in apps.

Answer (score 0):

For the current state of my system:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ lsb_release -a;snap list
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
Name                 Version    Rev   Tracking  Publisher           Notes
bw                   1.8.0      13    stable    bitwarden✓          -
core                 16-2.42.1  8039  stable    canonical✓          core
large-pcap-analyzer  3.6.0      97    stable    francesco-montorsi  -
mpv                  0.26.0     1     beta      casept              -
mpv-casept           0.24.0     2     stable    casept              disabled
walt@bat:~(0)$
```

This command will answer your question for MY system, at this time:

```
find /snap -type f -executable | \
  xargs file |\
  grep ELF |\
  cut -d: -f1 |\
  xargs -n 1 ldd |\
  grep /snap
```

1. Use `find` to find all the "executable" files under `/snap`.
2. Ask `file` - are the files scripts or execuables or what?
3. We only care about "ELF" files, as they're the ones using shared libraries.
4. `file` outputs the filename, a colon, some blanks and the description. All I want is the filename.
5. Then I use `xargs` to feed the filenames, one at a time (`-n 1`) to `ldd` to list the dynamic libraries used by each ELF executable.
6. Are any of the libraries in `/snap`?

   Nothings I see (other than "what if the other, library-containing snap isn't installed?") prevents it,